# Adding new line in react state string

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-state

I am currently creating a next JS application and using react states in that. I want to add a line break in a string value of the state. I tried multiple things like these but none of them work:
`setState("a \n b");`
`setState("a <br> b");`
`setState("a {\n} b");`
`setState("a {'\n'} b");`
Can someone please help with this

Edit: Sorry for such a vague question. Let me provide a little more context as to what my code currently looks like.

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState('abc')
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    setState('a');
    if(//some condition){
        setState(state + '<br />b')
    }else{
        setState(state + '<br />c')
    }
}
```

This is basically how I want my code to be. Any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a JSX element with `<br />`, and as string, if you want React to convert it to the correct DOM.

Use a fragment - `<Fragment>{prev state} <br /> b</Fragment>`, or the shorthand version (not supported in SO snippets) - `<>a <br /> b</>`.

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React

const Demo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('a')

  const add = () => {
    setText(t => <Fragment>{t} <br /> b</Fragment>)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
    
      <div>
      {text}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I have added some more information in the question. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Same thing - wrap it in fragment. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here:

1. is to use the `<pre/>` to display your text

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

export default Demo = _ => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('abc')
  
  return <div>
    <h2>Pre</h2>
    <button onClick={_ => setText(t => `${t}\nb` )}>Add</button>
    <pre>{text}</pre>
  </div>
}
```

2. use an array and render it's elements one-by-one

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default DemoList = _ => {
  const [text, setText] = useState([ "abc" ]);

  return<div>
    <h2>List</h2>
    <button onClick={_ => setText(t => ([ ...t, 'b']))}>Add</button>
    <div>{text.map( (t,ix) => <div key={ix}>{t}</div> )}</div>
  </div>
}
```